# Apply style to range of cells - Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, styles, apache-poi

I am looking for a solution to apply a style to a range of cells without having to loop on it.

Tried other solutions found here and there on stackoverflow, none of them worked.
For example, this does not work for me :

```
CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:B2");
short borderStyle = CellStyle.BORDER_THIN;
RegionUtil.setBorderBottom(borderStyle, region, activeSheet, excelWorkbook);
RegionUtil.setBorderTop(borderStyle, region, activeSheet, excelWorkbook);
RegionUtil.setBorderLeft(borderStyle, region, activeSheet, excelWorkbook);
RegionUtil.setBorderRight(borderStyle, region, activeSheet, excelWorkbook);
```

It adds borders on the outer edges of the selection, not to the cells inside.
I'd like to set a border to each and every cell inside the range. Is that even possible without looping ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can apply style to all cells within Range cells without applying it separately to single cell.

Try looping over each cell and apply all borders.

Here is a sample which might help you:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
cellStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
cellStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
cellStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
for(int i=region.getFirstRow();i<region.getLastRow();i++){
    Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
    for(int j=region.getFirstColumn();j<region.getLastColumn();j++){
        Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that what I finally ended up with.