# Apache POI- formatting

Tags: excel, kotlin, apache-poi

I am trying to provide colors to my headers(first row) to all of my excel sheets, but it's not working. Am i missing something? Can you please provide your feedback

```
val workbook = XSSFWorkbook(inputStream)
val style: CellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex())
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
val font: Font = workbook.createFont()
font.color = IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex()
style.setFont(font)
val Sheet1 = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1")
```

Comment: So, you've created a `CellStyle` and `Sheet`, but to whose cells on a sheet, this style should be applied? You need to explicitly define it in your code (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37782880/apply-style-to-range-of-cells-apache-poi)

Comment: @МихаилНафталь True, thanks. I am wondering whether we can add hexacode for colors? I want color which is not provided by IndexedColors. So, how can i add hexacode?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70425477/java-apache-poi-xssf-custom-rgb-cellbackground-not-working/70426030#70426030